# How to attach JavaFX2 javadoc jar automcatically with maven?

Tags: maven, javafx-2, javadoc, classification

I have in my pom.xml the dependency to jfxrt.jar, as a system scope one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
    <version>${java.fx.version}</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${javafx.abs.dir}</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

The problem is I would also like to attach the javadoc for this jar. So I went and downloaded the javafx2 javadoc,packed it into a jar, installed it in maven using install file and using javadoc as a classifier. The resulted jar has name javafx-2.2.4-javadoc.jar. As you know the main jar has name jfxrt.jar.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
    <version>${java.fx.version}</version>
    <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
</dependency>
```

When I call  mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc I get:

```
[INFO] The following files have NOT been resolved:
[INFO]    com.oracle:javafx:java-source:javadoc:2.2.4
```

What am I missing?

Regards,
Aurelian

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't want the javadoc as dependency, I guess, you probably just want the IDE to show the JavaDoc. I just tried the following in NetBeans and it worked:

- select a referenced JavaFX class and hit CTRL+SPACE to show the JavaDoc
- The pop-up provides links to configure the JavaDoc

Comment: From eclipse I can do it of course and it works, the thing is, when you add/remove a dependency, you regenerate the .classpath file, so you have to add the javadoc to javafx again. I wanted an automated solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

don't use the system dependency for binary, just install:install-file it into local repo as you did with the javadoc.. then it should start working

Comment: Hello, thanks, but isn't jfxrt dependent of native libraries? I suspect that jfxrt.jar loads native libraries from $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386 folder, so I really don't think this will work.